# Is it possibile to get pixel perfect dimensions of HTML text word (or words) using JS

Tags: javascript, html, text

I need get width and height of rendered html word without ANY white spaces and paddings on "edges".

I will specify: Width in pixels from first existing pixel of word on left to last existing pixel on right. etc. Dimensions of real rendered area of pixels without any "white space box" around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a mix of this [Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements) and setting the padding, margin and borders.

css:

```
p#no-style {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="no-style">TEXT</p>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#no-style').offsetWidth
```